i think my model is overfitting? any suggestions?
So I am using a deepfake detection dataset from kaggle and my model appears to be overfitting, Theres about 2000 images 1k for 'real' and 1k for the 'fake' class. All images are of faces. I am using VGG16, since its widely known as good for deepfake face detection.
Here are the results for the last 10 epochs:
Found 1632 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 204 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 205 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1234s 24s/step - loss: 0.1841 - accuracy: 0.9577 - val_loss: 0.7258 - val_accuracy: 0.6719
Epoch 2/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1168s 23s/step - loss: 0.1397 - accuracy: 0.9712 - val_loss: 0.7331 - val_accuracy: 0.6406
Epoch 3/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1186s 23s/step - loss: 0.1215 - accuracy: 0.9743 - val_loss: 0.7938 - val_accuracy: 0.6719
Epoch 4/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1187s 23s/step - loss: 0.0914 - accuracy: 0.9884 - val_loss: 0.8304 - val_accuracy: 0.6615
Epoch 5/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1188s 23s/step - loss: 0.0705 - accuracy: 0.9939 - val_loss: 0.9022 - val_accuracy: 0.6562
Epoch 6/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1155s 23s/step - loss: 0.0683 - accuracy: 0.9896 - val_loss: 0.9072 - val_accuracy: 0.6354
Epoch 7/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1154s 23s/step - loss: 0.0541 - accuracy: 0.9951 - val_loss: 0.8924 - val_accuracy: 0.6719
Epoch 8/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1175s 23s/step - loss: 0.0403 - accuracy: 0.9975 - val_loss: 0.9353 - val_accuracy: 0.6510
Epoch 9/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1189s 23s/step - loss: 0.0420 - accuracy: 0.9969 - val_loss: 1.0692 - val_accuracy: 0.6198
Epoch 10/10
51/51 [==============================] - 1185s 23s/step - loss: 0.0288 - accuracy: 0.9988 - val_loss: 1.0250 - val_accuracy: 0.6510
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py:3103: UserWarning: You are saving your model as an HDF5 file via `model.save()`. This file format is considered legacy. We recommend using instead the native Keras format, e.g. `model.save('my_model.keras')`.
  saving_api.save_model(
6/6 [==============================] - 135s 21s/step - loss: 1.1160 - accuracy: 0.6042
Test accuracy: 0.6041666865348816 t hese rae the results

Here's the code for the last 10 epochs if anyone is wondering:
from google.colab import drive
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

train_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/train'
val_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/val'
test_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/test'

#parameters
batch_size = 32
epochs = 5
image_shape = (224, 224)

saved_model_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/trained_model_updated.h5'
model = load_model(saved_model_path)

#preprocessing
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=image_shape,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=image_shape,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=image_shape,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary'
)


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=val_generator.samples // batch_size
)


model.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/trained_model_updated.h5')

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_generator, steps=test_generator.samples // batch_size)
print(f'Test accuracy: {test_acc}')


I ran the model for about 20 epochs and kept changing parameteres, applied data augmentation. Altough the model yielded good accuracy for the training data but remained stagnant at about 67% for the validation and test set.
The model did increase from 53% validation accuracy to 67% for the first 5 epochs but it remained stagnant for the last 15 epochs.
To confirm I also tried using some images from the internet but it didnt identify those correctly and would falsely classify some fake images as 'real'.
I am pretty sure its overfitting correct?
I dont have the computational resources to train a larger dataset, Any other solutions apart from increasing the dataset size? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

You can see that your training loss decreases and your validation loss increases at the same time. This is indeed overfitting. There are several things you can do to reduce overfitting:

Use more data augmentations and of different types (as you've mentioned)
Use regularization
Increase the learning rate
Change the optimizer and its parameters.

